# Android - The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type

Tags: java, android

Can anyone help keep getting this error
Im getting it at this line of code

```
TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textCocktailName);
```

Here's the full code snippet:

```
package com.drunktxtapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;


public class CocktailDetail {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bloody_mary);
        ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageCocktail);
        imageView1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bloodymary));
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bYoutube);
        TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textCocktailName);
        String cocktailName = getIntent().getStringExtra("Bloody Mary");
        t1.setText(cocktailName);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Alt-ehDc3fc")));
                }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Make a clean build.
2) Post the bloody_mary.xml

Cheers!

Comment: You should mark as correct the answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public class CocktailDetail { 
...
}
```

needs to be:

```
public class CocktailDetail extends Activity {
...
}
```

Comment: I wonder how did he pass @Override annotation in the first place

Comment: Yes me to so its solved now? @Adil Soomro Thanks for editing

Comment: Thats correct will mark as correct awnser when it allows me!

Answer (score 0):

**Extends your class with Activity class**

Comment: The same answer is said in a more precise way earlier. What is use of saying it again?